# Setting Driver manually in Spark Submit over Yarn Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I noticed that when I start a job in spark submit using yarn, the driver and executor nodes get set randomly. Is it possible to set this manually, so that when I collect the data and write it to file, it can be written on the same node every single time?

As of right now, the parameter I tried playing around with are:

`spark.yarn.am.port <driver-ip-address>`

and 

`spark.driver.hostname <driver-ip-address>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you submit to Yarn with `--master yarn --deploy-mode client`, the driver will be located on the node you are submitting from.

Also you can configure node labels for executors using  property: `spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression`

> A YARN node label expression that restricts the set of nodes executors will be scheduled on. Only versions of YARN greater than or equal to 2.6 support node label expressions, so when running against earlier versions, this property will be ignored.

Docs - [Running Spark on YARN - Latest Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html)

Answer (score 0):

A spark cluster can run in either yarncluster or yarn-client mode.

In yarn-cluster mode, the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster, and the client machine can go away after initiating the application.

In yarn-client mode, the driver runs in the client
process, and the application master is only used for requesting resources from YARN.

So as you see, depending upon the mode, the spark picks up the Application Master. Its not happened randomly until this stage. However, the worker nodes which the application master requests the resource manager to perform tasks will be randomly picked based on the availability of the worker nodes.